# Is there a term for an event and it's associated probability?

Tags: probability, terminology

I understand that an event is 1 or more outcomes and has a probability associated with it; however, I am wondering if there is a term for an event and it's associated probability. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Axiomatically, the empty set is *always* considered an event; thus there is no restriction whatever on the number of outcomes in an event.  This isn't some mathematical artificiality: the empty set represents impossible events--things that don't happen.  That's an essential part of any realistic model.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single term to jointly describe a single event and its probability.  This would be identified descriptively, in the way you have done it ---i.e., as "an event and its probability".  It is possible to describe the entire triple of the sample space $\Omega$, the set of events $\mathscr{G}$ on this sample space, and its probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.  We call the triple $(\Omega, \mathscr{G}, \mathbb{P})$ a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space).  This latter term jointly describes *all the events and their associated probabilities*.$^\dagger$

In theoretical papers on probability you will find that discussion of the problem usually begins with the specification of a probability space.  In papers on applied statistical work, it is more usual to start later on, with the specification of one or more random variables and their probability distributions.  In the latter case, it is common for a random variable and its distribution to be described symbolically:

> Let $X \sim \text{Ga}(\alpha, \beta)$ and ...

or have it described textually:

> Let $X$ be a random variable with a gamma distribution with shape $\alpha$ and rate $\beta$.  ...

In either case the events/random variables are separated from their probbabilities/probability distributions.

---

$^\dagger$ It also gives the sample space, but this is not really adding anything of values once we already have the set of all events.